# Why am I getting a network error on page refresh? (get request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, next.js

I'm making a get request to an API in a useEffect(). When I navigate to the page from the homepage it loads fine, but as soon as i refresh the page `http://localhost:3000/coins/coin` I get a `Unhandled Runtime Error: Error: Network Error`.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const id = query;
  return {
    props: { data: id },
  };
}

function index({ data }) {
  const coinURL = data.id; // bitcoin
  const apiEndpoint = `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinURL}`;
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
      const { data } = res;
      setCoinData(data);
    };
    const getCurrentUser = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session?.id}`
      );
      const { data } = res;
      setCurrentUser(data);
    };
    getData();
    getCurrentUser();

  }, [coinData, currentUser]);
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: please share more code snippet, so that we can answer it. Probably your `apiEndpoint` is coming from props.

Comment: I'm using getServerSideProps to get the url parameter. Then passing that id into the props the the main function.
`const apiEndpoint = https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinURL}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommending to do something like this:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(apiEndpoint);
        const { data } = res;
        setCoinData(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};

const getCurrentUser = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session?.id}`
        );
        const { data } = res;
        setCurrentUser(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getCurrentUser();
  }, [coinData, currentUser]);
```

if you do so, you will be able to view the exact error and fix it.

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem in itself. I'm a little confused as to why though... Is that because  I defined the functions outside the useEffect before calling them? or is it just because the try catch was added?

Comment: actually now its logging error aborting request in an infinite loop causing firefox to be unresponsive